# Angular 8 and routing between components without loosing state

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a kind of reusable search page, here is the scenario:

1. Employee page has an attribute of type Role, each employee has 1 Role set.
2. There is a page that searches available Roles
3. When search is done, user may select one out of results
4. When user selects the desired record, search page must return to Employee page with Role attribute set (or returned)

I would like to reuse role search page, because the query itself will be the same, what will change is just the action to be taken when select specific row.

I.e: Let's suppose there is a new page, with same job attribute, I would like to reuse job search page just replacing the callback on search results.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason for so many down votes? English is not my main language is there something wrong on undestanding what I'm trying to archieve? Anyway. Found the solution and it will give me flexibility to use same search logic for dialog and page at same time. I´ll answer my own question with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. It isn't based on original question which I was looking for a way to navigate from two pages to pick a record out of search results. Here is what I did:

1) Created an employee-search-form component which is responsible for search employees. It just make a query in database, list them in a table and add a button in each row to pick the record (employee-search-form).

2) Created a Dialog to implement a kind of data picker to be used in other forms which has relationship with this data (employee-search-picker)

3) Created a search page, which will present same search as a page instead of Dialog (employee-search-page)

4) Main app shows the usage of Dialog and Page and both uses the same search logic (app.component).

Here is the StackBlitz sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yjbtvj

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is to create 2 typescripts components for one unique template.
For example, you have a RoleSearchComponent.ts and EmployeeSearchComponent.ts, and both use the same html file for template, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-role-search',
  template: './search.component.html'
})
export class RoleSearchComponent
{
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-search',
  template: './search.component.html'
})
export class UserSearchComponent
{
}
```

That way you could use different callbacks and all for the same view.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your hint but I think it's not the ideal because if another component needs same search, it will create new TS class just to handle this communication. What I'll try is to create a modal with search logic, pass the callback as Output() and reuse it. I'll post a sample code in stackBlitz when I'm done.